# запрос через самосоединение таблиц MS Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Использование псевдонимов для самосоединения таблиц.
Вывести названия тех операторов, абоненты которых имеются как в Коломне, так и в Рязани.

```
SELECT  r1.*, r2.*, Абоненты.*, Операторы.*
FROM (Города AS r1 JOIN Города AS r2 ON r1.Код = r2.Код) JOIN
    (Абоненты JOIN Операторы ON Абоненты.Оператор = Операторы.Код) ON r1.Код = Абоненты.Город
WHERE (r2.Название = 'Рязань' OR r2.Название = 'Коломна') AND Абоненты.Город = r1.Код AND Абоненты.Город = r2.Код AND Абоненты.Оператор = Операторы.Код
```

я вот так написал, но нужно оставить только те строки, где оператор один и тот же
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[БД](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/DbZRDaWU0Ww1Gw)

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky СУБД MS Server Management Studio 18.12.1. В ней подключаю ранее созданную БД (на которую скинул ссыль). Создаю новый запрос (код выше). И у меня сейчас выводятся объединенная информация из всех таблиц,  где город Коломна или Рязань. Сейчас мне нужно из этого оставить только те строке, где Операторы совпадают. Без подзапросов, через самосоединение таблиц

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте ##1-4, чтобы получить СУБД MS Server версию: `SELECT @@VERSION;` Это нужно добавить к самому вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

вот так получилось:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  o1.Название [Название оператора]
FROM Абоненты As r1, Абоненты r2, Операторы o1, Операторы o2, Города g1, Города g2
WHERE g1.Название = 'Рязань' and g1.Код = r1.Город and r1.Оператор = o1.Код and g2.Название = 'Коломна' and g2.Код = r2.Город and r2.Оператор = o2.Код and r1.Оператор = r2.Оператор
```